# Accessing tableView.visibleCells causes header to reload

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

When I iterate through the visible cells of a `.grouped` `UITableView`, the section header delegate methods (title for header and height for header) are also called again.

Example: when the following loop runs

```
for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells {
    cell.doSomething();
}
```

The following method is called:

```
func tableView( tableView : UITableView,  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)->String
```

What is the purpose of this occurring? I am not updating the title nor am I (directly) requesting the layout to be redrawn.